# cakephp debug stop writing into logs

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Should i get the help to resolve the issue.

In my application we are using cakephp framework. Client has asking to change the debug functionality. I want write a notices, warnings, extra into log files. When debug level is >0 (greater then zero).Not going to write anything on debug level 0(zero). It should not display on front end errors in any level of debug. It will write on log files only if debug greater then (>0). for this could i get the solution.

Comment: You want to disable logging when debug = 0 (which it should **always** be on a production install)?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add an [environment](http://www.fullybaked.co.uk/articles/add-environment-variables-to-cakephp) variable to your cakephp framework, and the debug setting level will be different depend on your environment setting.

eg. production: debug == 0, dev: debug == 2

Comment: thanks for the solution. My question is I want use debug level 2 in production. Then i want write errors into Log files. But i don't want to see errors in front end. If debug level =0. I don't want write the errors into log files. Is it possible? Why i am asking is my log files are taking more space. So based on my interruption only we want to write into Log files.

Comment: Cake will always write errors into log regardless of your debug level setting: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html#error-configuration